# How to create histogram with fixed bin width in D3.js v4?

Tags: d3.js

Starting from [the official D3.js v4 histogram example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048450), I want to display a histogram of iris "PetalLength" values.

See http://codepen.io/netzwerg/pen/KNOYBy

My problem is that the last bin spans beyond the upper bound of the x-axis:

[image]

When looking at the bins, this makes perfect sense: They all have a width of `1`, except for the last one, which only spans from `x0: 6` to `x1: 6.9`.

Given that all svg rectangles are created with a fixed width (based on `bins[0]`), the overlap can be explained.

I can manually make the x-range "nicer" (rounding to `7`):

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain(d3.extent(values))
      .rangeRound([0, width])
      .nice();
```

which "fixes" the problem.

Alternatively, I could adjust the svg rectangle width calculation to be based on the `x0` and `x1` of each individual bin, which would draw the last bin with a narrower width.

But ultimately, my question is:

How do I tell `d3.histogram` to create bins which all have the same width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> Thresholds are defined as an array of values [x0, x1, …]. Any value less than x0 will be placed in the first bin; any value greater than or equal to x0 but less than x1 will be placed in the second bin; and so on.

That being said, your threshold is not correct. This:

```
.thresholds(x.ticks(5));
```

Is going to give you:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

And, because of that, the last bin was going just from `6.0` to `6.9` (a width of 0.9), being narrower than the previous ones (having a width of 1.0).

Instead of that, this should be your threshold:

```
.thresholds(d3.range(1, x.domain()[1], (x.domain()[1]-1)/6));
//          start----^    end---^          step----^
```

Which is going to give you the correct values:

```
[1, 1.983, 2.966, 3.95, 4.933, 5.916]
```

Here is your updated CodePen, with that change only: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBegWW?editors=0010

You can see that now the bins have the same width, which is `0.983`, and *none* of them end in the round tick anymore.

EDIT: According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396211/how-to-create-histogram-with-fixed-bin-width-in-d3-js-v4/41397676?noredirect=1#comment70071815_41397676) from the OP, with which I agree, this is a more readable alternative:

```
const [min, max] = d3.extent(values); 
const thresholds = d3.range(min, max, (max - min) / binCount);
```

Comment: PS: There is no *official D3 example*... that's just code that Mike Bostock writes to show D3 capabilities.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I am a bit shocked that such a simple use case requires so much complexity? According to the docs, `thresholds` can also specified as a count: _"If a count is specified instead of an array of thresholds, then the domain will be uniformly divided into approximately count bins"_. I cannot observe the division to be "uniform" though...

Comment: No, it's not, probably because Sturges' formula. And now you know: do not trust `d3.ticks()`...

Comment: Yes, I understand that `d3.ticks()` is not helpful here. But `thresholds` also accepts a `count` argument: [`histogram.thresholds([count])`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#histogram_thresholds)

Comment: Yes, I know. But, as I told you, the culprit is probably the Sturges' formula.

Comment: Ok – I just thought that you assumed I was still using `ticks`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No worries. Actually, I'm just guessing here. Maybe you can open an issue at GitHub... according to the docs, the `count` should create evenly spaced bins.

Comment: Great, let's wait for the answer.

Comment: I just saw Bostock's answer... So, at the end, using `d3.range` is the best option.

Comment: Yep, `d3.range` is the way to go. I think `const [min, max] = d3.extent(values);
const thresholds = d3.range(min, max, (max - min) / binCount);
` is more readable than `d3.range(1, x.domain()[1], (x.domain()[1]-1)/6)`. Would you mind changing it? I accept your answer in any case :-)